# JQUERY append data before sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got this html code

```
        <div class="chatp">
                <div class="chatpart">
                </div>
        </div>
```

And in my jquery i am trying to append

```
<div class='headchat'>

</div>
```

Inside  `chatp` but it appends it after `chatpart` and here is what happens

```
        <div class="chatp">
                <div class="chatpart">

                </div>

                <div class='headchat'>

               </div>
        </div>
```

What i want is

```
        <div class="chatp">
                <div class='headchat'>

               </div>
                <div class="chatpart">

                </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Show your script please.

Comment: Use `prepend` then.

Comment: Oh thanks!Did not know that function @RajaprabhuAravindasamy

Comment: There is also before/insertBefore

Comment: From what u said u r trying to append headchat before chat part , simply use prepend not append

Comment: @Musa are they both same?Why would jquery have 3 function that do the same thing?

Comment: They are not the same but all can be used to accomplish your need.

Comment: Okay thank you! @Musa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use prepend to append in start.

> Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the beginning of each element in the set of matched elements.

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/prepend/

Example:

```
<div class="chatp">
            <div class="chatpart">
            </div>
    </div>

<script>
    $('.chatp').prepend('<div class="headchat"></div>'); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Jquery prepend function $

```
$(".chatp").prepend("<div class='headchat'>  </div");
```